# Data Not Preserved in SQLite after the App Restarted

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My SQLIte database is not preserving the previously stored data.I am getting huge trouble for this.I have not found any suitable solution for this.Please some one help me out of this. I want to store my data after the app gets restarted. I am posting my DBhelper class and Main Method.Please help.I want to preserve the data.
This is My DBhelper Class.

**My DBHelper CLass:**

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_NAME = "photodb";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private DBhelper db;
public Context myContext;
File dbFile;
File dbFilepath;
AssetManager myassest;
AssetFileDescriptor me;
Cursor ch;

public DBhelper(Context myContext) { 

    super(myContext, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = myContext;

    System.out.println("Context value:--"+myContext);
    String state=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    System.out.println("My Storage State:-"+state);

}   

public void createDataBase(Context mycontext) throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(dbExist){
        System.out.println("Yes");
        String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();

        System.out.println("My database Path:--"+path);
    }
    if(!dbExist)
    {
        dbFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"PhotoApp");
        boolean flag=dbFile.mkdir();
        dbFilepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"PhotoApp"+"/"+"photodb");
        dbFilepath.createNewFile();


        System.out.println("Not..."+flag); 
        try {

            copyDataBase(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }   

}

public boolean checkDataBase()
{
    dbFile = new        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"photodb");
    return dbFile.exists();
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("photodb");
    String outFileName = dbFilepath.getAbsolutePath();
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    String myPath =      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"PhotoApp"+"/"+"photodb" ;

    System.out.println("MY DATABASE PATH:----"+myPath);
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,     SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {

    return super.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


}

public void add(String imagepath,String description,String location)
{
    long rowid;
    ContentValues myvalue = new ContentValues();
    myvalue.put("imagepath",imagepath);
    myvalue.put("description", description);
    myvalue.put("location", location);

    System.out.println("My Image Path:-"+imagepath+"My        Description:--"+description+"My location:--"+location);
    String sql = "insert into photodetails          values(null,'"+imagepath+"','"+description+"','"+location+"');";
    myDataBase.execSQL(sql);
    rowid = myDataBase.insert("photodetails", "id", myvalue);
    System.out.println("My Row ID is:----"+rowid);
    System.out.println("DB Updated");
}

public ArrayList<String> getimages(){

    ch = myDataBase.rawQuery("select imagepath from photodetails" , null);
    ArrayList <String> imageloc = new ArrayList<String>();


    if(ch.getCount() > 0){
        ch.moveToFirst();
        do
        {
            imageloc.add(ch.getString(0));

        }while(ch.moveToNext());
    }

    return imageloc;
}

         public ArrayList<String> getDescriptions(){

    ch = myDataBase.rawQuery("select description from photodetails" , null);

    ArrayList <String> des = new ArrayList<String>();


    if(ch.getCount() > 0){
        ch.moveToFirst();
        do
        {

            des.add(ch.getString(0));

        }while(ch.moveToNext());
    }

    return des;
}

   public ArrayList<String> getLocations(){

ch = myDataBase.rawQuery("select location from photodetails" , null);

ArrayList <String> local = new ArrayList<String>();

if(ch.getCount() > 0){
    ch.moveToFirst();
    do
    {

        local.add(ch.getString(0));
    }while(ch.moveToNext());
}

return local;

   }

  }
```

**This is My MainActivity :**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


DBhelper mydb;
Context cont;
ArrayList<String> myval = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mydb = new DBhelper(MainActivity.this);

    try {
        mydb.createDataBase(MainActivity.this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mydb.openDataBase();
    mydb.add("helloworld", "Done", "Yes");
    mydb.add("helloworld", "Done", "Yes");
    mydb.add("helloworld", "Done", "Yes");
    mydb.add("helloworld", "Done", "Yes");
    mydb.add("helloworld", "Done", "Yes");
    mydb.add("helloworld", "Done", "Yes");
    mydb.add("helloworld", "Done", "Yes");
    mydb.add("helloworld", "Done", "Yes");
    mydb.add("helloworld", "Done", "Yes");
    mydb.add("helloworld", "Done", "Yes");
    myval = mydb.getimages();
    int i=myval.size();
    System.out.println("SIze:----"+i);
    finish();
   // mydb.openDataBase();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Please check and please do post a solution..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method

```
public boolean checkDataBase()
{
    dbFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"photodb");
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

to

```
public boolean checkDataBase() {
        dbFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"PhotoApp");
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
```

Check it and let me know